# How can I get the connected Facebook page id of an Instagram business account programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

How can I get the Facebook page id which is connected to the instagram business account? Is there an Instagram API that is available for it? I have already searched through the Instagram developer documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** get Facebook Page ID from Instagram ID.

However, you can get the Instagram ID if you have the Facebook Page ID

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /{FB_PAGE_ID}?fields=instagram_business_account
```

and then:

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /{IG_BUSINESS_ID}?fields=id,ig_id,username
```

`ig_id` is the `instagram_id`, `id` is `instagram_business_id`